# Permission denied: u'/opt/cloudera/parcel-cache/CDH-5.3.3-1.cdh5.3.3.p0.5-precise.parcel.part'

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, cloudera, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager

I am trying to install hadoop cloudera cluster with 3 node all are ubuntu 12.04 machines. For that I have done following things.
I have created hduser in all machine and give the root permission to it by following command.

```
 sudo addgroup hadoop 
 sudo adduser --ingroup hadoop hduser 
 sudo adduser hduser sudo
 sudo su hduser
```

Then generated password less key for password less ssh by following command in all the machines.

**Machine Details:**

master-1 ip:192.168.0.101

slave-1 ip:192.168.0.102

slave-2 ip:192.168.0.103

**Commands:**

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -P "" 
ssh localhost
```

Then:

```
ssh-copy-id -i $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub hduser@192.168.0.101
ssh-copy-id -i $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub hduser@192.168.0.102 
ssh-copy-id -i $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub hduser@192.168.0.103
```

Then I configured ***etc/hosts*** file in all the machine in same format(just copy paste following line in all the machines)

```
127.0.0.1     localhost 
192.168.0.120 master-1
192.168.0.125 slave-2 
192.168.0.127 slave-2 

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts 
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback 
fe00::0 ip6-localnet 
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix 
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes 
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Then I downloaded and started installing cloudera management by following command.

```
$ wget http://archive.cloudera.com/cm5/installer/latest/cloudera-manager-installer.bin 
$ chmod u+x cloudera-manager-installer.bin 
$ sudo ./cloudera-manager-installer.bin
```

It was installing properly but in “Installing Selected Parcels” phase it gave me following error

[image]

I tried a lot but didn't get any solution please help to resolve it, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the cloudera documentation :

> Cloudera Manager stores parcels under /opt/cloudera, which by default is owned by cloudera-scm

What are the permissions on that directory ? Have you manually tested that the passwordless ssh works for user hduser and that he can write into this directory?

Last but not least, are you using the single user mode for this install ? If so, please refer the this [link](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/core/latest/topics/install_singleuser_reqts.html)

Comment: thanks for your answer, I just gave permission to hduser, to read write in opt folder and it is working.. thank you so much..